# Store grep output in an array

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, grep

I need to search a pattern in a directory and save the names of the files which contain it in an array.

Searching for pattern:

```
grep -HR "pattern" . | cut -d: -f1
```

This prints me all filenames that contain "pattern".

If I try:

```
targets=$(grep  -HR "pattern" . | cut -d: -f1)
length=${#targets[@]}
for ((i = 0; i != length; i++)); do
   echo "target $i: '${targets[i]}'"
done
```

This prints only one element that contains a string with all filnames.

```
output: target 0: 'file0 file1 .. fileN'
```

But I need:

```
 output: target 0: 'file0'
 output: target 1: 'file1'
 .....
 output: target N: 'fileN'
```

How can I achieve the result without doing a boring split operation on targets?

Comment: Other answer is a generic way to build an array by running any command and this question is specific to `grep --null -HR` to produce output with NUL bytes.

Answer (score 116, accepted):

Old answer (written in the year 2014) made an assumption that output filenames won't contain special characters like whitespaces or globs. Here is a safe way to read those special filenames into an array: (will work with older bash versions)

```bash
while IFS= read -rd ''; do
   targets+=("$REPLY")
done < <(grep --null -HRl "pattern" .)

# check content of array
declare -p targets
```

On BASH 4+ you can use `readarray` instead of a loop:

```bash
readarray -d '' -t targets < <(grep --null -HRl "pattern" .)
```

---

**Old Answer:**

You can use:

```
targets=($(grep -HRl "pattern" .))
```

Note use of `(...)` for array creation in BASH.

Also you can use `grep -l` to get only file names in `grep`'s output (as shown in my command).

Comment: spectacular! I was already taking a look at "-l" option, btw great hit. Can you explain why works adding two brackets?

Comment: That is syntax of array creation in BASH. If you remove outer `(..)` then you are merely assigning outout of `grep` to a simple shell variable which won't be treated as array.

Comment: If that is the possibility then use `grep --null` with `IFS=` to create array

Comment: Does this work with Posix-ly OS'es, like some of the BSDs and Solaris? I don't see [`-H` or `-R`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/utilities/grep.html).

Comment: `-R` may not be available in older `grep`. Alternative is to use `find -exec grep` on those systems

Comment: where does "$REPLY" come from?

Comment: `$REPLY` is internally set by `bash` if no variable name is provided.