# Error in getting array length in bash after passing to function

Tags: arrays, bash, shell

What is wrong in this approach I can't get correct value of array length

```
#!/bin/bash

foo(){

    val=$@
    len=${#val[@]}
    echo "Array contains: " $val
    echo "Array length is: " $len

}

var=(1 2 3)
foo ${var[@]}
```

Output:

```
Array contains: 1 2 3
Array length is: 1
```

Comment: This was helpful for me to identify gotchas in your script above:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/674333/how-to-pass-an-array-as-function-argument

Comment: `$#` is already the length of `$@`; you don't need to create an array first.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find the array length in unix shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1886374/608639), [Array Length is 1 in Bash scripting](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29621652/608639), etc.

Comment: Is it necessary to distinguish, whether the argument(s) are in fact an array? For example `foo 1 "a b" foobar` - shall it report an array of size 3, without any array being involved?

Comment: The proposed duplicate only tells you things the OP obviously already knows. The proper duplicate would say "use quotes everywhere unless you can explain why not."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change `val=$@` to `val=("${@}")` and you should be fine.

[This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/298941/issue-with-array-length-in-bash-script) in unix.stackexchange explains why:

> You're flattening the input into a single value.
>
> You should do
>
> ```
> list=("${@}")
> ```
>
> to maintain the array and the potential of whitespace in
>   arguments.
>
> If you miss out the " then something like `./script.sh "a b" 2 3 4` will
>   return a length of 5 because the first argument will be split up

Comment: This doesn't distinguish input `foo 1 2 3` and `var=(1 2 3); foo ${var[@]}` and the len and the contains need fixing too.

Comment: @Maroun What if I have to pass two arguments to the function the `list=("${@}") ` will merge the parameters into one  and will echo as a single array. How can I get each parameter separately by this approach.